# ping command on discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a command that would calculate my bot's ping, but I have a problem. It's telling me that `msg` is not defined. How am i supposed to define it? Here's my code:

```js
module.exports = {
 name: 'ping',
 description: "shows the bot/'s ping",
 execute(message, args) {
  message.channel.send('`ping is being calculated...`').then((message) => {
   const ping = msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp;
   message.edit(`${ping} ms`);
  });
 },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `message` is defined as `message`, not `msg`. Just edit this line:

```js
.then((msg) => {
 const ping = msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp;
 msg.edit(ping + 'ms');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code itself was correct, you just passed the wrong name as a parameter. Use `msg` instead of `message`.

```js
message.channel.send("ping is being calculated...").then((msg) => {
  const ping = msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp;
  message.edit(`${ping} ms`);
});
```